# How to remove all buttons from QInputDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have an input dialogue with combo-box, to choose between 2 options.

```
void MainWindow::on_UpdateCPUAssmblyBtn_clicked()
{
    if(!ui->AssemblyCpuSN->toPlainText().toStdString().empty())
    {
        QStringList items;
        items << tr("OUT_FOR_PCB_REPAIR") << tr("PCB_SCRAPPED");

        bool ok;
        std::string scrapcode="";
        QInputDialog* inputDialog = new QInputDialog();
        inputDialog->setOption(QInputDialog::NoButtons);

        QString item = inputDialog->getItem(NULL ,"Manufacturing Stage",
                                        "Please select the reason for removing the old board :", items, 0,false,
                                        &ok);
        if(ok && !item.isEmpty())
        scrapcode=item.toStdString();

        /* Do something with scrapcode */            
    }
    else
    {
        QPixmap pix("icons/angry1.png");
        mbox->setIconPixmap(pix);
        mbox->setWindowTitle("ERROR");
        mbox->setText("Disassociation is not successful.CPU SN is empty.");
        mbox->show();
    }
}
```

How to remove buttons from QInputDialog ? I am using 'NoButtons' flag but still it isn't helping.Kindly suggest any other approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QInputDialog::getItem` method is a [static method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm). In other words, it has nothing to do with your instantiated object (i.e. `inputDialog`). You should use the following code snippet instead.

```
QInputDialog* inputDialog = new QInputDialog();
inputDialog->setOption(QInputDialog::NoButtons);
inputDialog->setComboBoxItems(items);
inputDialog->setWindowTitle("Manufacturing Stage");
inputDialog->setLabelText("Please select the reason for removing the old board :");
inputDialog->show();
```

Result:

[image]

Once the dialog is closed, you can use `QInputDialog::textValue()` method to retrieve user's choice.